# Proof about Sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Does anyone know of an easy way to prove the following fact?

Given two sets $A$ and $B$ such that all of the elements of $A$ are equal and all of the elements of $B$ are equal, all of the elements of $A \cup B$ are equal if and only if $A \cap B \neq \emptyset$.

I'd like to use it for a problem on my homework but I'm not sure if I can use it without proof. It seems super trivial but I'm having a hard time showing it in a rigorous manner.

Comment: What do you mean by "all of the elements of $A$ are equal?" Unless you're working with multisets, wouldn't that just make $A$ a singleton?

Comment: What does "all the elements of $A$ are equal" mean?  Just that $|A|=0$ or $1$ for ordinary (non-multi) sets.

Comment: Sets do not typically contain duplicate elements (by standard definition).  Thus, your sets $A$ and $B$ should only contain one element.  That should be fairly simple to work with.

Comment: @anorton: The word "typically" is redundant.

Comment: @AsafKaragila and "basically" among others

Comment: I've noticed that you have asked several questions during the last 24 hours. I wanted to make sure that you are aware of the quotas 50 questions/30 days and 6 questions/24 hours, so that you can plan posting your questions accordingly. (If you try to post more questions, stackexchange software will not allow you to do so.) For more details see [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/4770/).

Answer (score 0):

With your hypotheses, you get $A=\{a\}$ and $B=\{b\}$ and thus $A\cup B=\{a,b\}$. Then $a= b$ implies $A\cap B\neq\emptyset$ and conversely, if $A\cap B\neq\emptyset$ this implies that $a= b$.

Comment: It should be $ a=b $ in both instances.

Comment: thanks for the observation!